# Do electrons always emit photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

You know how the way that electrons repel other electrons can be explained using particle interaction?...

Well, in that explanation an electron emits a photon...where does it get the energy to emit that photon...I mean its not like it KNOWS to emit a photon when it gets near an electron, so it must be emmiting photons in every direction...where does it get the energy to do that?
Thanx in advance

Comment: It emits *virtual* photons, off shell, *all the time*. Read up in Feynman’s popular booklet.

Comment: [Here](https://www.amazon.com/QED-Strange-Theory-Light-Matter/dp/0691024170) is the booklet... virtual without math. Read up and only then  come back.

Comment: "Virtual photons" do not deserve the name. These are just the Fourier components of the EM potential.

Comment: @my2cts "Virtual photons" are only a name for the Fourier components of the EM potential. The only thing wrong with that name is that ignorant people might think it means they have something to do with photons. But if we changed physics names so that ignorant people won't misunderstand, we'd have to change half the names in physics. Probably all the names in quantum mechanics.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Actually, nothing is emitted. "Virtual photons" do not travel.

Comment: @my2cts Sigh... There seems to be a massive effort to banish virtual photons as a useful concept. "Emitted" is *obviously* the shared metaphor involving the Feynman diagram term with off-shell photons; if one is careful, as Feynman is in his booklet cited, one *may* talk about such terms as a virtual process, a useful fantasy. Just because the metaphor is often abused and misunderstood, is not a good reason to banish it. Go to a blackboard where practitioners are computing an amplitude: if you don't hear "emitted",  there is something wrong...

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am not in favor of such terminology as it is only confusing many, among which the OP. Yet, as long as it is clear to everyone at the blackboard  that Feynman diagrams are nothing else but a notation for terms of a perturbation expansion, why not?

Comment: @my2cts Indeed, after a semester of QFT, nobody is unclear about it. Now, the atrocious metaphors, images, etc in the popular science press, videos, etc.. is another matter. I adduced Feynman's booklet because he did care about communicating to the mathematically unsophisticated...

Answer (score 3):

Based on various professional scientists'/teachers' youtube channel comments: virtual particles really captivate the non-expert and cause nothing but confusion.

Problem (1) is that the expert always explains them in terms of old-fashioned perturbation theory, in which the energy to exist for a short time is borrowed from the vacuum per the H.U.P. The virtual particles are time ordered, so one particle emits one and the other absorbs one.  In beta decay, they always drop the 1/2 of the process where the d-quark absorbs a W+ that has already produced the final state leptons (and likewise in other processes)...they tell half the story.

In modern Lorentz covariant formulations, all diagrams conserve energy and momentum at each vertex, so the question "where does the energy come from" is basically meaningless.

People also ask how emitting/receiving a photon can cause attraction: again, 4-momentum is conserved at all vertices, so the photon has the correct 4 momentum in a scattering process. Then they ask: which particle emits and which receives? Well, Feynman diagrams with an exchange particle encompass both time-ordered diagrams in a covariant way: the question is again, meaningless in the context of the theory.

Then comes bound states and "continuous emission"...which may make sense in the context of self energy and renormalization, but that is total advanced.

The simple tree level diagrams are used in scattering theory. Here we have initial and final states approximated by free particle states, and the transition matrix encompasses all possible paths....that is not solvable, so perturbation theory is used, and that's where the diagrams come in.

The tree level diagram is an exchange of a single virtual particle. The particle is completely off shell. For instance, in s channel:

$$ e^++e^- \rightarrow \gamma \rightarrow X $$

at a collider, the photon has zero momentum and lots of energy (it's basically a massive particle at rest in the lab...a photon?). Conversely, in scattering (t channel) in the Breit-frame, the virtual photon has zero energy and space-like momentum, so treating that as "real" can only cause confusion.

So the non-expert can waste a lot of time reading to much into virtual particles. At the tree level, they are completely defined by the kinematics of the initial and final states, and at loop level, you have to integrate of all 4-momenta, so anything goes.

Nevertheless, to the expert, they are very useful for understand physical processes, e.g. the Rosenbluth separation in $ep$ scattering: the longitudinal and transverse polarization of the virtual photon (again: defined by kinematics) can be used to separate the electric and magnetic responses of the proton at fixed $Q^2$.

In parity violating elastic $ep$ scattering, the entire signal can be viewed as interference between 1 photon exchange and 1 $Z^0$ exchange, which is very handy.

So, in summary, they are very useful for experts, and cause lots of confusion for non-experts, and most of the common non-expert questions fall into the "that's not what virtual particle are" category.

Answer (score 2):

You, like many others, have fallen victim to a rude and inaccurate analogy. Such analogies are always misleading, they cause more questions than they give answers.

To you, your question seems completely logical to ask, but to a trained physicist it is a meaningless question.

The only way to truly understand the physics of electron-photon interaction is to study the mathematics of Quantum Electrodynamics, one of the simplest models of interacting Quantum Field Theory. There are no royal roads to science. Do not trust analogies, even when repeated by senior researchers. They think they are making the subject more approachable to the general public, but it mostly results in widespread confusion and misconception.

The photon that electrons "use to mediate interaction" is actually not at all a physical object, or anything of the sort. It is a mathematical label that is used to diagrammatically encode terms – complicated mathematical expressions – in the quantum field theoretical formula that gives you an approximate probability of observing an end state of the field (configuration of electrons with certain values of coordinate/momenta) given an initial state of the field. This quantity is called the [S-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix).

Unfortunately, I cannot possibly explain to you Quantum Field Theory in a single answer here, but I strongly encourage you to study it. Fortunately there are plenty of beginner friendly textbooks out there in the year 2020.

Comment: QED is currently the best way we have of understanding this... it's not "the only way to truly understand." That sounds like religion...

Comment: @N.Steinle I'm not sure what you mean by this. QED is definitely not the final word in science. But none of the pre-QED ideas do such a good job of explaining particle physics processes as QED does. That claim is scientific because it is falsifiable – just go through all such ideas, there are finitely many of them.

Comment: You've literally written, "The only way to truly understand the physics." That is false, as you just admitted above, one day we'll probably have something better. To say that QED is the "only way to truly understand" it is to say that it's the end of the conversation. But we all know that's not true. That kind of certainty is for religion, not science.

Comment: @N.Steinle "as you just admitted above, one day we'll probably have something better" we already have something better – the Standard Model. But QED is a good approximation to the standard model, and it is sufficient to explain electron-photon interactions at low enough energies, while all previous attempts are insufficient. When we finally have a theory of BSM physics, it will have SM as an approximation to it, and QED will hence too be an aproximation, sufficient to understand electron-photon interactions with good accuracy. Therefore I stand by "the only way".

Comment: You're going in circles now. If QED was literally "the only way to truly understand" it then there'd be no need for a more general model..... AS you say, QED is an approximately good description, as is any theory, in its respective range of validity. Even still, that does not imply that its the "only way" of understanding things in that range of validity....Schwinger had a different description of QED, for example.

Comment: @N.Steinle for most phenomena, there is a description that is still approximate, but already good enough to say "I understand". You won't understand gravitational bending of light with Newton's law of gravity, but you will understand it with General Relativity. You don't need quantum gravity to say "I understand bending of light". "If QED was literally "the only way to truly understand" it then there'd be no need for a more general model" – this is completely false. I said, "to understand the electron-photon interactions", not "to understand everything about the Universe".

Comment: Since you're not actually willing to address what I'm saying this is my last comment here. Youre' just going in circles. If Newtonian mechanics was the "only true way" of understanding relativity and gravity then there'd be no need for general relativity. I never said you do need a more general theory to understand something specific... You understand that A -> B does not necessarily imply that B -> A, right? As I said, there are others ways to understand quantum description of photon-electron interaction than Feynman's QED, but you're not interested in actually discussing that.

Comment: @N.Steinle not that Prof. Legolasov needs my help, but I think in this context it's safe to interpret his words in the obvious sense they were intended: "the only way to truly understand the statement behind your misconception is to study QED, assuming that statement correctly describes the physics of the electron-photon interaction"

Comment: @user2723984 sorry those aren't the words he used, so I'm not going to assume his intention.

Comment: @N.Steinle instead, you are going to assume he worships Feynman diagrams?

Comment: @user2723984 Ha! No of course not. I am simply holding him accountable for the words he wrote... As is expected on this website.

Comment: @N.Steinle there is nothing wrong with my wording. user2723984 immediately understood what I meant to say, it is not my problem that you don't.

Comment: It is your problem because it is misleading. But if you don't care that's not my problem. It's not my fault you are unresponsive to suggestions/advice. You're statement as-is is blatantly false.

Comment: I think this conversation has devolved enough for it to be appropriate for me to mention that I worship Feynman diagrams.